# Malformed request when trying to trade cognito code for jwt

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

EDIT:

I was reading the documentation wrong. In this world of JSON I didn't notice the request was sending form data. Silly mistake.

It was also the wrong endpoint.

The request should have looked like:

```
fetch(
    'https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token/',
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: 
            `?redirect_uri=${redirectUri}` +
            `&code=${clientCode}` +
            `&client_id=${clientId}` +
            `&client_secret=${clientSecret}` +
            '&grant_type=authorization_code'
    }
)
```

---

I'm trying to trade a token obtained with the code flow in cognito's login page, but the request responds with a status 400 "malformed request".

The documentation I am following is: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/authorization-code-grant.html#access-token-request

I am using the browser to make the following request:

```
   fetch(
        'https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token/' +
        `?redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUri)}` +
        `&code=${encodeURIComponent(clientCode)}` +
        `&client_id=${encodeURIComponent(clientId)}` +
        `&client_secret=${encodeURIComponent(clientSecret)}` +
        '&grant_type=authorization_code',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
            }
        }
    )
```

Which results in the client sending the following request:
`POST`

`https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token/?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Floggedin&code=<code>&client_id=<client_id>o&client_secret=<client_secret>&grant_type=authorization_code`

The response:

```
{
    "error_description": "Malformed request",
    "error":"invalid_request"
}
```

Comment: So what does the actual request made by the client look like?

Comment: Updated the post to include the actual request

Comment: You just appended all the parameters to the URL here, which makes them _GET_ parameters … Go check f.e. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch to figure out how to make a _proper_ POST request.

Comment: I realise that, the request the browser made was a POST request, and it seems AWS's docs are asking for url params in the POST request. Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Yes, you’re reading that wrong. The URL you need to make your request to is `https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token`, no more, no less. The POST parameters belong into the request body.

Comment: Oh I see! Cool. Now it's telling me I have an issue with my client - but that's probably an unrelated issue